# Can not detect intent (Dialogflow CX)

Tags: reactjs, express, dialogflow-es, chatbot

Following is the data result from console.
I got always the same text reply as user input
e.g. I said hi, it responses hi; I said how are you , it responses how are you

```
Data returned from detectIntent: {
  responseId: 'da86eeb0-8214-4b47-a065-2f77b4a6eb1e',
  queryResult: {
    text: 'hi',
    languageCode: 'en',
    parameters: { welcomeword: 'hi' },
    responseMessages: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    currentPage: {
      name: 'projects/yufantest-bmqj/locations/global/agents/6f2db33e-1f23-462d-a8c8-a5a4adf1f21d/flows/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/pages/ff8a689c-09fc-41de-a30e-7541437a2cd1',
      displayName: 'Asking policies'
    },
    intent: {
      name: 'projects/yufantest-bmqj/locations/global/agents/6f2db33e-1f23-462d-a8c8-a5a4adf1f21d/intents/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
      displayName: 'Default Welcome Intent'
    },
    intentDetectionConfidence: 1,
    diagnosticInfo: {
      'Session Id': '7x291fgm8vu-w7t4lta4j4r',
      'Transition Targets Chain': [Array],
      'Triggered Transition Names': [Array],
      'Execution Sequence': [Array],
      'Alternative Matched Intents': [Array],
      'Response Id': 'da86eeb0-8214-4b47-a065-2f77b4a6eb1e'
    },
    match: {
      intent: [Object],
      parameters: [Object],
      resolvedInput: 'hi',
      matchType: 'INTENT',
      confidence: 1
    },
    advancedSettings: { loggingSettings: {} }
  },
  responseType: 'FINAL'
}
```

tried to re-train the intent, it does not work